# Возможность буферизации в rsyslog

Tags: linux, администрирование

Предположим 1 ПК на linux шлёт логи 2 ПК на linux средствами rsyslog. В какой то момент 2 ПК выключается, а 1 ПК по идее продолжает слать ему логи. Можно ли как то остановить это пересылку или сделать какой-то буфер, в который бы "сливались" эти события пока 2 ПК не будет включен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Изучите [failover](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/tutorials/failover_syslog_server.html) в rsyslog. В вашем случае (нет secondary-серверов) конфигурация будет такой:

```
*.* @@pс2.example.com
$ActionExecOnlyWhenPreviousIsSuspended on
& /var/log/localbuffer
$ActionExecOnlyWhenPreviousIsSuspended off
```